# What does "generalizes the tag object's storage" mean?

Tags: java, jsp

could anyone please clarify the meaning of line **generalizes the tag object's storage of attributes** in the following line of [Head First Servlets & JSP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005405/) (page no. 555):

> **One solution would be to put all of the attributes into a hashtable. This
>   generalizes the tag object's storage
>   of attributes, but what about all
>   these setter methods? We can't get rid
>   of them unless there's a way to tell
>   the JSP engine to set the tag
>   attributes using a generic
>   interface.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dude, you need to get a better book, this one doesn't seem very good judging by the number of clarifications you've been asking for :)

Comment: as for the quote: One solution to what? What is the topic here?

Comment: There are a lot of Head First books -- which one do you mean?

Comment: It's Servlet & Jsp book. BTW, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Generalizes" in this context means that you can write one function or one small piece of code that implements all of your cases rather than writing each case separately.  I don't have that book, but it looks like it replaces something like:

```
 String attr1;
 String attr2;
 String attr3;
```

with

```
 Hashtable<String, String> attributes;
```

That's generalizing the storage -- the code is meant to show a generic hashtable that maps strings to strings -- you would use something like this

```
 attributes["attr1"] = "value";
```

The other code would be used something like this:

```
 attr1 = "value";
```